# If $p(x+y)^2=5$ and $q (x-y)^2=3$, then the simplified value of $p^2(x+y)^2+4pqxy-q^2(x-y)^2$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $p(x+y)^2=5$ and $q (x-y)^2=3$, then the simplified value of $p^2(x+y)^2+4pqxy-q^2(x-y)^2$ is?

Answer: $2(p+q)$

Comment: We already have $$(x+y)^2,(x-y)^2$$  Can't you find $xy$ from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x+y)^2 = 5/p$$

$$(x-y)^2 = 3/q$$

$$\implies 4xy = 5/p - 3/q$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$5p-3q+pq(\frac{5}{p}-\frac{3}{q})=2p+2q=2(p+q)$$